# Remove multiple commas at the end of lines using Notepad++ regex replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text below with data in a CSV file

```
2,3
4,5
6,7
```

When I save an open this in notepad++, it has extra commas like

```
2,3,,,,
4,5,,
6,7,,,,,
```

like you see, there are variable number of leading commas,

I tried a regex match using:

```
/,{2,}/
```

I have selected the **regular expressions** combo-box from the search mode in `ctrl + H` Replace box.

For some reason this is not working. What do I need to do to match multiple comma and not get rid of single comma?

Is there a better way to get this done in notepad++?

Answer (score 7):

Regex:

```
,{2,}$
```

Replacement string:

```
empty string
```

This will replace two or more trailing commas with an empty string. To remove all the trailing commas then use `,+$` regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+(?:,\d+)?\K.*$
```

You can use this.Replace by `empty string`.This will work with data like `2,3,`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/9